# Equivalency of Set Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

This is a very simple question.

Let's say there is $ Z_{1} \cup Z_{2} $
Where $ Z_{1} = \emptyset $ and $  Z_{2} $ =  $  \left\{ x \mspace{4mu} | \mspace{4mu} x \in \mathbb{R},\mspace{4mu} 9<x  \right\} $

Would $ Z_{1} \cup Z_{2} $ =  $  \left\{ x \mspace{4mu}|\mspace{4mu} x = \emptyset \mspace{4mu}\mspace{4mu} or  \mspace{4mu}\mspace{4mu}x \in \mathbb{R}, 9<x  \right\} $
be equivalent to  $ Z_{1} \cup Z_{2} $ =  $  \left\{ x \mspace{4mu}| \mspace{4mu}\mspace{4mu}x \in \mathbb{R}, 9<x  \right\} $ ?

I think it is, but I am not sure if the empty set is in the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's $\{x \mid x \in \emptyset \text{ or } x \in \mathbb{R}, 9 < x \}$. And the first clause is never true (there are no elements in the empty set!) so can be omitted.

So you are left with just $Z_2$ again.

Comment: So if I I compare two intervals for intersection and there are no elements that intersect, and I want to define the set. Would I say $ x \in \emptyset $ or $ x = \emptyset $ or $\emptyset$.

Comment: Two disjoint open intervals have intersection $= \emptyset$